# Windows 10 WSL2 - Electron App via X-Server with blank screen

Tags: ubuntu, electron, windows-10, wsl-2, xserver

I want to run my Electron Apps in version 16 on Ubuntu with WSL2 and x-server (VcXsrv). The application opens under Windows 10, but unfortunately the screen is blank. Even if I just start the Electron Shell without the app.

I did it according to the following instructions:
https://gist.github.com/caseywatts/9700b402b6b51d1d6af9f0b206739770#file-electron-on-wsl2-md
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL#Running_Graphical_Applications
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242

According to the output, I think it would be the graphics driver. I have a GeForce GTX 1050.

The output in the terminal is:

```
gregor@SurfaceBook2:/mnt/c/Users/Gregor$ electron --no-sandbox

Electron 16.0.4 - Build cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS
Usage: electron [options] [path]

A path to an Electron app may be specified. It must be one of the following:
  - index.js file.
  - Folder containing a package.json file.
  - Folder containing an index.js file.
  - .html/.htm file.
  - http://, https://, or file:// URL.

Options:
  -i, --interactive     Open a REPL to the main process.
  -r, --require         Module to preload (option can be repeated).
  -v, --version         Print the version.
  -a, --abi             Print the Node ABI version.
[12778:1211/161727.622001:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[12778:1211/161727.627323:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[12778:1211/161727.627589:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
[12778:1211/161727.641556:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(63)] Failed to enable receiving udev events.
[12778:1211/161727.714353:ERROR:bus.cc(393)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[12802:1211/161729.353666:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:894 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supportable.
[12802:1211/161729.354148:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(782)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supportable.
[12802:1211/161729.354530:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1382)] eglInitialize OpenGL failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED, trying next display type
[12802:1211/161729.356451:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] Display.cpp:894 (initialize): ANGLE Display::initialize error 12289: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[12802:1211/161729.356766:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(782)] EGL Driver message (Critical) eglInitialize: Could not create a backing OpenGL context.
[12802:1211/161729.357035:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(1382)] eglInitialize OpenGLES failed with error EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
[12802:1211/161729.357404:ERROR:gl_ozone_egl.cc(20)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
[12802:1211/161729.360064:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(161)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[12838:1211/161730.970595:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(376)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[12807:1211/161730.979034:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(125)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
[12807:1211/161731.133776:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(47)] Descriptor access mode (0) differs from expected (2)
gregor@SurfaceBook2:/mnt/c/Users/Gregor$
```

xcalc works wonderfully. Must be a chromium graphic problem.

[image]

Maybe someone had the same problem and was able to solve it elegantly.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm currently running into the same problem